# How to order and limit sql query with join in ASC

Tags: sql

I have a query to order by id of the first table

```
$req = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT a.amt    AS req_amt,
       a.date   AS req_date,
       b.NAME   AS user_name,
       b.status AS user_status,
       b.ref    AS ref_email,
       b.id     AS user_id,
       b.email  AS user_email,
       a.id     AS request_id
FROM   `help_requests` a
       JOIN `users` b
         ON ( a.USER = b.id )
WHERE  b.status = '1'
ORDER  BY a.id DESC 
LIMIT 500
");//ASC
```

This query works if I order by DESC but if I put ASC it will not return any data(that is when I loop nothing comes out as if my table rows are empty)

Comment: ASC is default try without that in the code. Also if by SQL you are querying a SQL server which uses T-SQL use the TOP 500 instead of limit

Comment: `ASC/DESC` will never make any difference in number of records returned. Some thing else is wrong in your application code

Comment: The only explanation which comes to mind is that you have 500 or more IDs which appear first when ordering ascending, which also have NULL or empty records.

Comment: I would agree in part with Tim. If IDs column allows nulls filter those out, yet that would still have data for the other columns

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen its like you are pointing to a good direction!